# Invalid cast exception SqlSyncprovider()

Tags: microsoft-sync-framework

I am using Microsoft Sync framework and this issue has no clear solution in Google.

I am trying to create a client provider for SQLServer Client as below

```
`public class SampleClientSyncProvider : SqlSyncProvider`
```

But I am running in to invalid cast exception when setting the 'localprovider' below

Exception:

> System.InvalidCastException was unhandled
>   Message=Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.ClientSyncProvider
>   Source=Microsoft.Synchronization.Data

Code called:

```
 public class SampleSyncAgent : SyncAgent
{
    public SampleSyncAgent()
    {
        this.LocalProvider = new SampleClientSyncProvider();
```

Please help if you can ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SyncAgent works out of the box only with SqlCeClientSyncProvider/DbServerSyncProvider.

SqlSyncProvider works with SyncOrchestrator.

check in the docs on the difference between offline providers and collaboration providers.

I suggest you use the SqlSyncProvider/SyncOrchestrator instead.

Comment: Thanks, I got it working. One question, is SyncOrchestrator of 2.1 same as syncAgent of v 1.0 of the framework ?

Comment: yes and no. yes in that similar to the syncagent, its the one that orchestrates the synchronization between two providers. no, in that internally they behave differently.